# Are there any other CSS properties like currentColor?

Tags: css

It would be cool if `currentWidth` existed. Are there any other things like `currentColor` in the spec?

Comment: `currentWidth` of what? there's the `vw` unit which is related to current viewport width.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://caniuse.com/#search=current .

Comment: why do we need `currentWidth` and `currentColor`?

Comment: You want it for a script to process? .. or what? .. and if script, use `window.getComputedStyle()`

Comment: How would you use this? Like.. `.foo { height: currentWidth * .5; }`? You could do that with JavaScript

Comment: @XanderLuciano `calc(currentWidth * .5)`, if something like that did exist.

Comment: @SumitSahay *"why do we need `currentWidth` and `currentColor`?"* So we can do things like `border: 1px solid currentColor`. That is, re-use the currently assigned (e.g. `color: red`) color to get a border in the same color as the text without having to use CSS variables. I can see many use-cases especially when you can not change the color that is being assigned to make it use CSS variables.

Comment: @XanderLuciano *"You could do that with JavaScript"* That's the other way around. You can literally say that about *every* CSS solution. Javascript is super powerful and can do everything that CSS can and more. But it's also much more difficult, error-prone, and often, slow. I have nearly 2 decades of web development experience and call myself a Javascript guru, but my rule of thumb is, if it can be easily done in CSS, do it in CSS. Because you will get the native speed of the browser and don't need to load scripts and maintain them etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're asking for a list of *values* whose *computed values* are relative to *other values.*

And that list is short. If we comb through the [CSS 3 Values and Units Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values), we find that:

- [`inherit`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade-4/#valdef-all-inherit) takes the parent value.
- [`unset`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade-4/#valdef-all-unset) can operate like `inherit`.
- [`currentColor`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#currentColor-def) uses the current font color.

These are units that specify relative values:

- `%` is a percentage of the parent value.
- [`em`](http://%60vw%60,%20%60vh%60,%20%60vmin%60%20and%20%60vmax%60%20are%20all%20relative%20to%20the%20viewport.) is relative to the current font size. [`rem`](http://%60vw%60,%20%60vh%60,%20%60vmin%60%20and%20%60vmax%60%20are%20all%20relative%20to%20the%20viewport.) is similar, but to the root element's font size.
- [`vw`, `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) are all relative to the viewport.
- [`ex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), to the height of the current font -- sort of counts.
- [`ch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ch), to the width of the "0" character in the current font -- also sort of counts.

These [functional values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#functional-notations) don't *exactly* count but are worth mentioning:

- [`calc()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-calc) allows mathematically-calculated values.
- [`toggle()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-toggle) lets child elements cycle through values.
- [`attr()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-attr) returns the value of an element's attribute.

And historically:

- CSS 2 offers now-deprecated [System Colors](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#css-system).

Comment: Nice! Do you happen to know where I can find a list of all deprecated CSS properties/values?

Comment: There might be a place that documents deprecated features, but I'm not aware of it. Oddly enough the CSS 3 spec only mentions deprecation on System Colors.

Comment: Changes since the 11 June 2015 Candidate Recomendation are:
Dropped toggle() for lack of implementations.

Comment: This is a great answer but I don't like it because I hoped there would be more!  